# Drupal 8 twig debug not showing all the variables

Tags: twig, xdebug, drupal-8

I have MAMP Pro with xdebug and twig debug in drupal 8.6 setup. When I call the `{{breakpoint()}}` method in my template I get VS Code to show me the variables but not all of the keys.

Specifically I want to look into the `node.Owner` variable. However when I look in `$context -> node` there is no `Owner` key anywhere to be found. The field exists (I can use `dump(node.Owner)` ) without a problem so I am wondering why it isn't showing in the debug variable inspector.

[image: debugger 1]
[image: debugger 2]

Comment: Did you try calling `breakpoint()` after calling `node.Owner` - There could be some lazyloading involved in here

Comment: yeah I had a `{{dump(node.Owner)}}` call right above the `{{breakpoint()}}` call.